# Docker Compose Shared Folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I have successfully mounted a folder from Windows 10 to boot2docker.
Now I want to make docker-compose.yml to mount the folder from boot2docker into the container.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you created in Virtual Box a shared folder win_share and mounted it in boot-to-docker like below:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf win_share /shared
```

You can  mount the directory in the docker-compose.yml as follow:

```
...
volumes:
- /shared:/path/in/container
...
```